# Change the background color of a div using a loop Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, background-color

I am using a v-for for loading dashboard data in VueJs.

```html
<b-row>
  <b-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" v-for="(item, key) in dashboardItems" :key="key">
    <b-card class="mb-2 card-border change-color-div">
      <b-row>
        <b-card-title class="text-muted mb-0 title-text">{{ key }}</b-card-title>
      </b-row>
      <b-row>
        <b-card-text class="card-body-text">{{ item }}</b-card-text>
      </b-row>
    </b-card>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

The output looks as below

[image]

But I need to display different background colors for each `b-card`. How can I do that using a loop?

**expected output**

[image]

Comment: ask the color value of from API otherwise you can generate random colors or specify 7 different colors (if you don't want the color to change randomly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify color of an item in the looping object. For example:

```
dashboardItems: [
  {item: 'text1', color: 'grey', key: 234},
  {item: 'text2', color: 'blue', key: 2334},
]
```

Then in your `v-for`loop you can create a [style binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles)

```
<b-col 
    cols="12"
    sm="6" 
    md="4" 
    lg="3" 
    v-for="(item, key) in dashboardItems" :key="key"
>
    <b-card 
        class="mb-2 card-border change-color-div"
        :style="{'background-color': item.color}"
    >
        ......
    </b-card>
</b-col>
```